# "exception in main thread" when creating .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to create a .jar file. I have attempted many times, but each time when I do

`java -jar NoughtsAndCrosses.jar`
it tells me that there is an exception in my main thread. I am using notepad and command prompt, not eclipse.

Does anyone have an answer to my question?

Thanks for reading

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: exception in thread main java.lang.noclassdeffounderror

Comment: Please show us how you are creating the JAR file.  The way you are running the app requires an *executable* JAR, which has to be created in a specific way ... or else it won't work.

Comment: I tried using jar cfe NoughtsAndCrosses.jar NoughtsAndCrosses NoughtsAndCrosses.class

Answer (score 0):

Creation of jar file
jar cvfm MyJarName.jar manifest.txt *.class

For executing the jar file 
java -jar

To make an executable jar file you need to add manifest file, which contains the main class .
I hope you have not added the main class or  If you are using any third party jar files it will not placed in classpath.

Comment: Can you explain, please? I am quite new to java and I do not understand.

Comment: what is there to explain? But you have to tell me whether you are using an third party jar file or not? You can refer the link for creation of executable jar file http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Comment: What is a third party jar file?

Comment: external jar file e.g apache.commons.io

Comment: No. I do not think I am using that. I have never heard of it before.

Comment: ok . no issues.. just follow the link. before that you can google it. you get lot of stuff..

Comment: Ok. I think I can safely say that I am not using any of that in my programme

Comment: I did what it said and I STILL have the exception! :(